# Fixed values of breakpoints (psi) for Segmented R

Tags: r

Hi I am using segmented from R. After doing it I obtain 10 breakpoints so now I would like to take a subset of this breakpoints and do segmented again since for my porpouse 10 breakpoints its too much. Also I would like to take some specific breakpoints from the ten that I have obtain.

```
# Segmented does not allow referenced to the dataframe class
lx <- life_table$lx
x <- life_table$x
#First we create a linear model
LinearMod <- lm(lx~x)
seg_5 <- segmented(LinearMod, seg.Z = ~x)
vec_breakp = as.numeric(seg_5$psi[,2])
vec_psi <- vec_breakp[4:6]
seg_mod <- segmented(LinearMod, seg.Z = ~x, psi = vec_breakp)

The output is:
    ***Regression Model with Segmented Relationship(s)***

Call: 
segmented.lm(obj = LinearMod, seg.Z = ~x, psi = vec_psi)

Estimated Break-Point(s):

           Est. St.Err

psi1.x  21.448  0.572
psi2.x 134.938  3.214
psi3.x 525.438 10.565
```

The breakpoints are not exactly the ones that I have chosen.
It is possible to fixed them?.